# How should I set up my bucket policy so I can deploy to S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've been working on this a long time and I am getting nowhere.

I created a user and it gave me

```
AWSAccessKeyId
AWSSecretKey
```

I created a bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::abc9876/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now when I use a gulp program to upload to the bucket I see this:

[20:53:58] Starting 'deploy'...
[20:53:58] Finished 'deploy' after 25 ms
[20:53:58] [cache]  app.js
Process terminated with code 0.

To me it looks like it should have worked but when I go to the console I cannot see anything in my bucket.

Can someone tell me if my bucket policy looks correct and give me some suggestions on what I could do to test out the uploading. Could I for example test this out from the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to manage access control on S3. These different mechanisms can be used simultaneously, and the authorization of a request will be the result of the interaction of all the rules in all these mechanisms. Things can get confusing!

Let's try to make things easier to understand. You have:

- **IAM policies** - these are policies you define for specific Users or Groups (or Roles, but let's not get into that...).
- **S3 bucket policies** - these are policies that you define at the bucket level.
- **S3 ACLs (access control lists)** - these are rules that you define both at the bucket level and the object level. This is that *permissions area* mentioned on a comment to another answer.

Whenever you send a request to S3, e.g. downloading an object, the request will be processed by an authorization system. This system will calculate the *union* of all the policies/rules described above, and then will follow a process that can be simplified as follows:

- If there is any rule explicitly denying the request, it's denied. Period. Otherwise...
- Otherwise, if there is any rule explicitly allowing the request, it's allowed. Period. Otherwise...
- Otherwise, the request is denied.

Let's say you have all the mechanisms in place. For the request to be accepted, you must not have any rules Denying that request, and need to have at least one rule allowing that request.

---

### Making your policies easier to understand...

*My suggestion to you is to **simplify your policies***. Choose one access control mechanism and use stick to that one.

In your specific situation, from your very brief description, I feel that using **IAM policies** could be a good idea. You can use either an IAM User Policy (that you define and attach specifically to your IAM User) or an IAM Group Policy (that you define and attach to a group your IAM User belongs to). Let's forget about IAM Roles, that is a whole different story.

Then delete your ACLs and Bucket Policies. Your requests should be allowed then.

As an additional hint, make sure the software you are using to upload objects to S3 is actually using those 2 API calls: `PutObject` and `PutObjectAcl`. Keep in mind that **S3 supports multi-part upload, through the use of a different set of API calls**. If your tool is doing multi-part uploads under the hood, then be sure to allow those API calls as well (many tools will, including the AWS CLI, and many SDKs have a higher level S3 API that will do that as well)!

---

For more information on this matter, I'd suggest the following post from the AWS Security Blog:

> [**IAM policies and Bucket Policies and ACLs! Oh My! (Controlling Access to S3 Resources)**](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/TxPOJBY6FE360K/IAM-policies-and-Bucket-Policies-and-ACLs-Oh-My-Controlling-Access-to-S3-Resourc)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define "Principal": "*" , since you have already created a IAM user

The Bucket Policy looks fine, if there was a problem with access it would have given you an appropriate error.

Just make sure your "Keyname" is correct while calling AWS APIs, the keyname which uniquely identifies the object in a bucket.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html

Comment: Actually, it's pretty important to define "Principal" here -- that's how you'd restrict to whom that bucket policy applies. In its current form, the bucket policy allows anyone to write to that bucket. More info: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-bucket-user-policy-specifying-principal-intro.html

Comment: @BrunoReis - I am getting confused here. There's a bucket policy and there is also a permissions area. Should I be giving everyone permission to view and the using the bucket policy to allow one user to do the uploading, deleting etc. or should I do everything in the bucket policy and not bother about grantee everyone? If you would be kind enough to put your comments into an answer then I can accept that if it explains what I need. Thanks

Comment: @Alan - just added an answer. It can quickly become a pain to manage permissions, if it's not crystal clear what you are doing. Hopefully that answer will make it easier to understand what's going on. Let me know if you have any other questions on this matter.